# How to use various connection strings in WPF and DataSet in Debug and Release mode?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, connection-string

I have a lot of CRUD applications written using WPF and [DataSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31ct733b.aspx)

My connection strings are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Depboard.Properties.Settings.DepartmentConnectionString"
            connectionString="ReleaseServer" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
        <add name="Debug"
            connectionString="DebugServer" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

And these applications have many rows of code:

```
private static string ConnStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ReleaseServer"].
                                                                       ConnectionString;
```

Moreover, `DataSet` uses by default "ReleaseServer" connection string.

I am really scared to change all of lines of code with the connection string when I will switch between `Debug` and `Release` mode.

Is there a simple approach to change connection string in `DataSet` and in program between `Debug` and `Release` modes without modifying code?

Comment: How about using Config Transformations?
http://johan.driessen.se/posts/Visual-Studio-feature---Preview-web.config-transforms
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using `#if DEBUG`?

Create a static class that you will use to obtain your server name:

```
public static class ServerName
{
    #if DEBUG

        const string SERVER = "DebugServer";

    #else

        const string SERVER = "ReleaseServer";

    #endif

    public static string Name => SERVER;
}
```

Then use that when initialising your connection string:

```
private static string ConnStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[ServerName.Name].ConnectionString;
```

This is, however, a bit of a dirty fix in my opinion.

The applications should really be using dependency injection and possibly a dependency container, along with patterns such as the Repository Pattern, to keep all the initialisation code in one place (at a suitable "seam"). If you use DI correctly, there's only one place where you need a connection string.

Comment: thanks! What is about `DataSet`? It is always set to one `"Depboard.Properties.Settings.DepartmentConnectionString"` and it never changes till I change it in `app.config` file.

Comment: @StepUp For the App.Config file, you might be able to follow the instructions here: https://mitasoft.wordpress.com/2011/09/28/multipleappconfig/

Comment: is there simpler solution?:)

Comment: @StepUp Not that I know of. :(